# Alternative to Expect.all using elm-test?

Tags: elm, elm-test

I'm new to Elm and I have some question about elm-test. I try to have multiple expect in the same test, but didn't find how. so here is what I've done for now but it's not really expressive

```
suite : Test
suite =
    describe "2048-elm"
        [ test "moveLeftWithZero" <|
            \_ ->
                let
                    expectedCases =
                        [ ( [ 2, 0, 0, 2 ], [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ] )
                        , ( [ 2, 2, 0, 4 ], [ 4, 4, 0, 0 ] )
                        , ( [ 0, 0, 0, 4 ], [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ] )
                        , ( [ 0, 0, 2, 4 ], [ 2, 4, 0, 0 ] )
                        , ( [ 2, 4, 2, 4 ], [ 2, 4, 2, 4 ] )
                        , ( [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 4, 4, 0, 0 ] )
                        ]

                    toTest =
                        List.map (\expected -> ( Tuple.first expected, Main.moveLeftWithZero (Tuple.first expected) )) expectedCases
                in
                Expect.equal expectedCases toTest
        ]
```

I tried with `Expect.all` but it does not seems to do what I want

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code, so it can be read. Instead of triple backtics as is used in Slack, use the code formatting of SO. The editor has a button for this, or you can just add indentation manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what you mean with `Expect.all` does not seem to do what you want?